# How to get configuration in ASP.NET Core Middleware when the configuration file is in a subfolder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 API project I'm loading a configuration from subfolder:

```cs
// Startup.cs
public Startup(IHostEnvironment env)
{
  var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
  builder
  .SetBasePath(Path.Join(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Configurations"))
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
  .AddEnvironmentVariables();

  Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

In my middleware I'm also reading from configuration:

```cs
// MyMiddleware.cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
  var appSettings = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
  var apiKey = appSettings.GetValue<string>(SETTINGS_NAME);
  ...
  await _next(context);
}
```

But in the middleware config values are not loaded when the files are not in the root project. How can I tell middleware to read configuration from a specific folder?

Thanks

Comment: in my opinion you should load the configuration only once on the entry point not on the startup... so for example in Program.cs then you use that configuration everywhere. At least that is how I do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are correct up to the point but above configuration needs to be in program.cs

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
            {
                config
                .SetBasePath(Path.Join(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Configurations"))
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

The way you do is that it applicable only the point when you configure it but you need it at host level so you access in all controller and middleware.